# Session was already closed

Tags: hibernate

I know this error has come because there is no session found to update the object. when I use below code I get "Session Was already Closed"

```
@RequestMapping(value = Route.ediBillingLogCreate,method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public @ResponseBody String updateEdiBillingLog(@ModelAttribute("SearchEntityObject")EdiBilling404LogIiss ediBilling404LogIiss, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
    {

BigDecimal id=ediBilling404LogIiss.getEdiBilling404LogUid();

    if(id!=null && id.intValue()>0){            
        ediBillingLogService.updateupdateEdiBillingLog(ediBilling404LogIiss);
    }       
    return "success";
}
```

But when I use the similar code in another controller I do not get this error. 
for Eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Route.nvoccShipperForwarderSave) 
            public @ResponseBody
            String saveForwarderDetails(@ModelAttribute("BlForwarderParties") BlHousePartiesIiss blHousePartiesIiss ,BindingResult result, SessionStatus status,@RequestParam String blNumber,@RequestParam long partyId, @RequestParam String blHouseUid) throws Exception {
                if (result.hasErrors()) {
                    LOG.info("Errors" + result.toString());
                }       

                Long id=null;           
                if(partyId==0){             
                 id=nvoccBlHouseService.saveNewRecord(blHousePartiesIiss);
                }
                else
                {
                BlHousePartiesIiss idOld=nvoccBlHouseService.updatePartiesDetails(blHousePartiesIiss);
                id=idOld.getHousePartyId();
                }
                return "success";

            }
```

//PrintStackTrace

```
SEVERE: [baseWebAppExceptionHandler] Response exception: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Session was already closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed!
Mar 17, 2016 2:16:06 PM com.intellect.eShip.webapp.BaseControllerAdvice exceptionHandler
SEVERE: [baseWebAppExceptionHandler] Response getMessages: Session was already closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed!
Mar 17, 2016 2:16:06 PM com.intellect.eShip.webapp.BaseControllerAdvice exceptionHandler
SEVERE: [baseWebAppExceptionHandler] printStrackTrace:  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:794)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:665)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.intellect.eShip.service.ediOperations.EdiBillingLogService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$40b36cb3.updateupdateEdiBillingLog(<generated>)
com.intellect.eShip.webapp.controller.ediOperations.EdiBillingLogController.updateEdiBillingLog(EdiBillingLogController.java:130)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

//updateEdiBillingLog

```
public void updateupdateEdiBillingLog(
            EdiBilling404LogIiss ediBilling404LogIiss) {
        try{

            ediBillingLogDAO.update(ediBilling404LogIiss);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
Which in turn Calls below method  
@Transactional
    public T update(T object) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(object);
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return object;
    }
```

I would like to bring to your notice the difference between BlHousePartiesIiss and EdiBilling404LogIiss .
BlHousePartiesIiss  has one primary key. where in EdiBilling404LogIiss combination of keys makes a primary key.

Why is there a difference in behavior? when I  am using the current session in both cases.

Comment: Posting the complete stacktrace would help. Also can you post `ediBillingLogService.updateupdateEdiBillingLog` method

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Madhusudana.

Comment: with spring managing the transaction it is not needed to call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();` and even `setting the flush mode is is not needed`. Can you remove those 2 lines and test.

Comment: I tried using
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();  session.beginTransaction();session.update(ediBilling404LogIiss); It deosnot throw any error but it doesnot update the object in the table either.
But when I use
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(ediBilling404LogIiss);
    session.flush();
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();
It throws "Session Was Closed Error". could not find any reason yet.

Comment: I found the reason for session was closed. The reason is my class has got more than one primary key. so while updating hibernate was not able identify the unique identifier as it has more than one identifier. We either need to embed those three keys into one class and use that class's reference as unique identifier or we need to have only one unique identifier in our class. Correct me if I am wrong.Thank you Madhusudana for your reponse.